# Simple Xml получить атрибуты

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Проблема с файлом или есть способы о которых мне не известно.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('all-brands_ua.xml');
```

Ссылка на xml - https://gorgany.eu/xmlxls/xml_content/all-brands_ua.xml

Не выводит атрибуты в тегах `<category id="4123" parentID="3666">Туристичні намети</category>`

В тегах item все работает прекрасно.

Comment: приведенный вами код не выводит?

Comment: @splash58 Конкретно с тегом category не выводит. С другими проблемы нет

Comment: код приведите в вопросе

Comment: у меня никаких проблем получить список id из категорий не возникло